# Spring annotation wrapper for controller parameter

Tags: spring, rest, validation, http, request

I have RestController with method:

```
@CrossOrigin
@PostMapping("/change_password")
@ApiOperation(value = "Change user password")
public AbstractResponseConfirmationDTO changePassword(@Valid @RequestBody ChangePasswordDTO passwordDTO) {
    return authorizedEmployeeServiceImpl.changePassword(passwordDTO);
}
```

Here i have @Valid and @RequestBody annotations. How can i wrap them into one annotation? I want it to be like this:

```
@CrossOrigin
@PostMapping("/change_password")
@ApiOperation(value = "Change user password")
public AbstractResponseConfirmationDTO changePassword(@AuthorizedRequestBody ChangePasswordDTO passwordDTO) {
    return authorizedEmployeeServiceImpl.changePassword(passwordDTO);
}
```

@RequestBody and @Valid cannot be applied to type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this. For you to create a annotation with other annotations the annotations should be of ElementType `TYPE`.

`@Valid` and `@RequestBody`doesn't have `ElementType.TYPE`.

```
@Target({ METHOD, FIELD, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface Valid {
}
```

This means you can use this annotation only on method, field, constructor and parameter. Not on class level.

and

```
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface RequestBody {
}
```

This you can only use at parameter level.